# LibreOffice API controlling impress slide show

Tags: api, slideshow, libreoffice

Is it possible to control slide show (LibreOffice Impress) using Java/C++ API?

I looked for information in API documentation but without any success.

Comment: Andrew Pitonyak's book "OpenOffice Macros Explained" has a section "Draw and Impress" with code examples to control the slide show under the subsection "Presentations".  The book is available as a free download from [http://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php](http://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php).  The book's code examples are in StarBasic, but the API names are the same regardless of language so you should be able to translate to Java (or C++) without to much trouble.